# Issues when using logger package in r-markdown when initializing log_errors()

Tags: r, logging, r-markdown, error-logging, rscript

I created a function to initialize logging using logger package and to save the logs entries in a temporary file in the tempdir() given by R.

```
init_logger <- function() {
  library(logger)
  temporary_directory <- tempdir()
  date_time_current <- format(Sys.time(), "log_%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S_")
  tmp <- tempfile(pattern = date_time_current, tmpdir = temporary_directory, fileext = '.txt')
  configuration_logger(tmp)
  log_info('Logging starting:')
  return(tmp)
  }

configuration_logger <- function(tmp){
  log_appender(appender_file(tmp))
  log_threshold(TRACE)
  log_formatter(formatter_paste)
  log_layout(layout_simple)
  log_errors()

}
```

The function above initializes the log and I am calling this `mypackage::init_logger()` in another function `mypackage::get_data(client, dimensions, metrics, start_date, end_date, ...)` where I want to capture certain information as well as any errors that might occur, therefore the `log_errors()` is crucial in order to debug if anything goes wrong.
Everything works fine if this function is in a regular R-script, but it does not work the same way in a R-markdown.

If I force an error in a markdown:

````
```{r}
library(mypackage)
library(magrittr)
```

```{r}
clients <- "client_x"
end_date <- Sys.Date() - 1
# FORCING ERROR HERE... 
start_date <- "not_defined"
#start_date <- Sys.Date() - 30
```

```{r}
new_data <- get_data(client = clients, 
                     start_date = start_date,
                     end_date = end_date,
                     dimension, metrics, ...)
```
````

In this case  I get the following error in the console and no log-file gets generated.

```
Error in globalCallingHandlers(error = function(m) { : 
  should not be called with handlers on the stack
```

Now if I have the same lines of code but instead in just a regular `.R` script file the actual log files gets generated and the error I am expecting also is recorded in the log file created.

```
INFO [2022-07-26 11:26:51] Logging starting:
INFO [2022-07-26 11:26:52] Starting Function: -get_data()-. File: -data.R-
ERROR [2022-07-26 11:26:59] nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp...
```

I know for certain that the cause of this issue is when `log_errors()` is called in the function `configuration_logger()` that is used in `init_logger()`. I tried removing this line of code and the log files get generated in both the .`Rmd` rmarkdown and `.R` script when calling the same function, but then any errors occurring do not get recorded in the log file but they are just printed in the console instead.

Anyone knows why this is occurring in `r-markdowns` only when `log_errors()` is initialized and if there is a possible solution to it since I would like to record any errors that might occur in my function in the log file that gets created.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue, "both R markdown and logger try to use the same globalCallingHandlers -- which is not supported."

[Logger issue 104](https://github.com/daroczig/logger/issues/104)

[Logger issue 70](https://github.com/daroczig/logger/issues/70)

There is no solution yet, but I hope this saves some debugging time for anyone in the future with similar issues.